Modeling trend in binary variable over time
I have a dataset with repeated measures per subject, with 100 subjects. My outcome of interest is a binary variable assessed on an hourly basis, of if the subject met a threshold value through a test. The majority of subjects have about 150 measurements, although there are a handful with fewer measurements.
My primary interest is to model the trend of the outcome over the study time period. I do have other covariates, such as height group, age group, weight group, and perceived level of difficulty of each test (i.e. 0-10). These covariates are factors. I also have the pulse rate at the time of measurement ( a continuous variable ranging from 50-150)
My time variable is currently expressed as hours from the first test for each subject.
I am struggling with choosing the correct model. I am attempting to use a binomial mixed effect model with random effect for subject.
    glmer(outcome~time+height+age+weight+difficulty+pulse+(1|subject), family=binomial)

My questions are:

Is a binomial mixed effect model appropriate to trend the outcome over the study time period?
I am getting error message for variables on different scales. Should hour and pulse be scaled using a method such as dividing by 1000?
When comparing between the glmer model above and a glm model with no random effect, the random effect does not appear to be significant. Should I abandon the glmer and use the glm model, despite having repeated measures?

I am very new to statistical modelling, so I apologize for my naivety!

I would use a Generalized Additive Model (GAM) to capture potentially nonlinear temporal trends while also making inferences about other terms in your model. You can use the binomial() family in a gam() in the {mgcv} library to set these up. There are many helpful resources on GAMs, but probably none better as an intro than the docs on the {mgcv} help pages (i.e.: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/gam.models.html). You can also estimate different trends per subject, which may be appropriate, using a hierarchical GAM. This site has a lot of help on these models

Thank you @NicholasClark, I appreciate you sharing this resource! a GAM sounds like it would be quite appropriate for this situation.
